# What hook to change thumbnails size in WooCommerce product loops

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails, hook-woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce. I have added some products to linked products and that is displaying below the details of the single product as a "You may also like…" and I am getting below output

[image]

Now, My issue is, I am getting the `150*150` size of images. I have to display the actual size of the images.

@LoicTheAztec I tried the below link as you suggested

[Customizing loop product image via a hook in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773845/customizing-loop-product-image-via-a-hook-in-woocommerce/50774377#50774377)

and I changed from  `$size = 'woocommerce_thumbnail';` to  `$size = 'size-woocommerce_thumbnail';` and it's displaying the actual size of images.
Is this the correct way to do it?

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
function custom_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    global $product;
    $size = 'size-woocommerce_thumbnail';

    $image_size = apply_filters( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', $size );

    echo $product ? $product->get_image( $image_size ) : '';
}
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, content-product.php displaying all the hooks

Comment: Yes, I have to customize the page "You may also like" section. Is it possible to change HTML?

Comment: I found a composite filter hook to be used , see my answer below.

Comment: @user9437856 It could also depend on a custom CSS rule. If you inspect the 600x400 image from the browser what size do you see? The image may actually be the right size but a CSS rule may cause it to display at a different size.

Comment: @Vdgaetano, Yes, I have 550*550 images and if I inspects then I am getting 150*150 images.  I added code in the question which solved my issue.